# Get Library Name from WolframLibraryData

Tags: librarylink

When developing with LibraryLink, is there any way to get the function name from inside the library ?

I don't think there is a way to find out the name of the function that have been used to access the C function like the `FunctionX` shown in the example bellow.

```
FunctionX = LibraryFunctionLoad[...]
```

I suspect there might be something in `WolframRuntimeData` but this one is not documented anywhere.

Is there an way to finf out the name of the shared object from inside the library ? Some kind of `argv[0]` for shared object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is no clear mention, in a recent [discussion](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1525995) on wolfram community it seems there is really no way as of now.